# MySQL error on inserting row into 2 separate tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert data into 2 separate tables at the same time - but getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO
StoreTable (Name, Price, Description, ImageName, Colors, Sizes, SKU,' at line 1
```

Here's my code:

```
// INSERT the NEW Store Item & its image into the database:
$query = "BEGIN; INSERT INTO StoreTable(Name, Price, Description, ImageName, Colors, 
Sizes, SKU, Category, DateAdded) VALUES ('". $newStoreItemName ."', '". $newStoreItemPrice ."',
'". $newStoreItemDescription ."', '". $newStoreItemImageName ."',
'". $newStoreItemColors ."',  '". $newStoreItemSizes ."',  '".$StoreNewItemSKU."',  
'".$newStoreItemCategory."', '".$storeItemDateAdded."'); 
INSERT INTO StoreCategoriesTable (CategoryName, DateModified) VALUES('".$newStoreItemCategory ."',
'". $storeItemDateAdded."'); COMMIT;";

    // Echo the query statement to see what it looks like:
    echo "Here's the full query:<br/><br/>" .$query. "<br/><br/>";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

That echo statement shows what looks like a correct MySQL statement - but obviously its not since I'm getting an error:

```
BEGIN; INSERT INTO StoreTable (Name, Price, Description, ImageName, Colors, 
Sizes, SKU, Category, DateAdded) VALUES ('Shirt', '12.98', '100% Cotton', 
'TShirt.Png', 'Red, Blue, Black', 'S, M, L', '88nnkLb', 'Childrens Apparel',
'2015-03-28 15:51:41'); INSERT INTO StoreCategoriesTable (CategoryName,
DateModified) VALUES('Childrens Apparel', '2015-03-28 15:51:41'); COMMIT;
```

Being that I'm an iOS developer with minimal MySQL knowledge, I'd appreciate any and all help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a security feature of php, you will only be able to run one query at a time using `mysqli::query()`. I recommend you break these into separate queries, making sure they save properly, and then committing them to the database. There is a great example which can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php).

Also: You can take a look at [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), which can achieve a similar result.

I do have one other thing to mention here. **Please be mindful of security!** Executing queries like this opens the database to sql injection attacks. I would **highly recommend** you take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) on how to bind parameters to queries. (This will automagically escape everything needed to ensure your queries run without issue).

Comment: Also worth looking at database transactions as an alternative to multi_query

Comment: ok, I'm looking into it.... but forgive my ignorance: should I be using the "procedural style" method in that example, or the "Object oriented style"?

Comment: It looks like you're using object oriented style for your example. I'd recommend you keep sticking with that.